# form object has no attribute 'isValid' in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

If i print `request.POST.username` and `request.POST.password`, i am getting right data. But i am not able to verify form. And i am not able to get `cleaned_data`.

**views.py**

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.isValid():
            print "coming"
        return render_to_response('html/index.html')
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
        c = {'logInForm': form, }
        return render_to_response('html/index.html', c, RequestContext(request))
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    .....
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

    <form class="form-signin" action="login" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ logInForm.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We don't want no mixedCase [naming style](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not using the method correctly. The correct method is `is_valid`

[Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view)

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid(): # <<<< Correct!
            print "coming"
        return render_to_response('html/index.html')
```

Answer (score 2):

The proper method name is `is_valid`.